# 3d array with negative index - c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I need a 3 dimensional array which supports negative indices.
Something similar to boost::multi_array, where I could specify bounds for each dimension, ie:

```
int xMin = -5; int xMax = 7;
int yMin = 3;  int yMax = 10;
int zMin = -8; int zMax = -2;
SuperArray<float> ar;
ar.setBounds(xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, zMin, zMax);
ar[-3][5][-5] = 1.0f;
```

Basically, it's indexing voxel subspace in 3D :)
Is there anything ready outthere, or am I to create this by myself ?
thanks !

Comment: Logically, what you want to do with the multidimensional array does not make sense. You could define yourself a limit, which represents your 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the size of each dimension to `Max-Min`. Then when you want to access an array element, add `-Min` to each index. So for your dimensions, you would declare:

```
float ar[12][7][6];
```

Then to access the element you want, you do:

```
ar[-3-(-5)][5-3][-5-(-8)] = 1.0f;
```

You should be able to write a class that hides all these transformations (which is what the Boost library is doing).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do a translation?

Lets say the array size is:

```
 d1 = 100
 d2 = 100
 d3 = 100
 [d1][d2][d3]
 // where index 0 = -50 and index 99 = 50

 //Pseudo code
 // x = -1; y = 2; z = 2;
 value = array[d1/2+x][d2/2 + y][d3/2 +z];
```